# Replacing getters and setters with properties while subclassing

Tags: python, properties, wxpython

I am working with WxPython - a GUI library for Python. Almost all the attributes of this library are handled through getters and setters such as `Frame.GetName` or `Panel.SetBackgroundColour`. This is also true for its Python 3 port (named Phoenix). The widgets supplied by WxPython are commonly used by subclassing them and overriding their getters and setters. The library also provides classes to create new widgets, and I am, at the moment, trying to create one.

The question is: is it ok to replace this getter/setter pattern with properties? It is possible to do it, no doubt, but should I do it? This will create the following conflicts:

- the attributes I added to the subclass (or the widget I made) will be property-like
- the ones I didn't override will remain as getters and setters
- Users will have to switch between the above two.

Here's an example:

```
# Say, I made a widget called FancyButton. Here's the aftermath:
mybutton = FancyButton()
mybutton.SetLabel("Quack") # This is legacy code from superclass
mybutton.hover_colour = "Blue" # This is new code with property style
```

Is this design pattern commonplace? Should I stick with getters and setters?

Comment: Not true for Phoenix, most if not all get/set stuff is available as a property, see e.g.: http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Window.html#property-summary-properties-summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add properties for the base class's getters/setters in your subclass if you like.  Properties are very Pythonic, but not very high-performance.  Also, they don't work well when you have to do magic like `__getattr__`, but I use them often.

The only real reason to avoid them is if they confuse the user -- for example, because of things changing that he didn't expect, or because of the amount of execution time they take.